# disable laravel's built in error screen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, error-handling

I want to disable Laravel's error screen that shows the errors/exceptions with debugging information and functions trace. Mostly because I'm using Laravel as mobile API backend and those responses are harder to read on a mobile device.

**Please notice that I want the errors**, but not the fancy error page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean by "want the errors", but the linked post should give you what you need.

Answer (score 21):

Go to Laravel project -> app folder-> config folder -> app.php set

```
'debug' => false,
```

This will show a simple error page like Ops! Something went wrong.

**Edit:**

Laravel App facade provides a way to way catch the exceptions using error method as mentioned in the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors)

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception)
{
    // handle your exception
});
```

You can place App::error method in the filters.php

and Laravel is using Symfony to display those pages if you want to further go down. I have not really tried to change this thing, maybe someone will come up with a better answer.

Comment: I want the error, I just don't want the error screen

Comment: Ok, I have edited the answer according to my knowledge. Hope this helps.

Comment: This can be done in the .env file by setting debug to false

Comment: @kratos Now a screen with an error number appears.