# How to show proper errors other then the developer error in laravel

Tags: laravel, exception, error-handling

I'm working on laravel application during work when something went wrong it shows me an error like to help the developer.
But when I show to the customer and something went wrong its shows the same error which is not for the user.
How I can fix this if something went wrong its just show "***something went wrong*** " other then developer error:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable laravel's built in error screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665061/disable-laravels-built-in-error-screen)

Comment: On your env if you set `APP_DEBUG=false` then you don't see any debug error

Comment: @MrEvers no this one

Comment: @STA I tried this but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your code in the try catch block and return the view in the catch block like this.

```
try{
   // Your amazing code
}
catch(\Exception $e){
  return view('your_custom_view');
}
```

And set the `APP_DEBUG=false` in the `.env` for the production environment.

Comment: Should i write the exception for each method or another way to write the whole code in exception