# Remove stack trace from Laravel error page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, ignition

How would i remove the lengthy stack trace errors that Laravel uses by default? (i understand it is using "Ignition")

Some resources that i've found that did not help:

- [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665061/disable-laravels-built-in-error-screen) only mentions how to disable error reporting altogether
- when i write anything in a `render()` method in the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583567/customize-laravel-error-reporting-to-remove-stack-trace) i only get error 500 without any output.
- person [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438560/disable-laravels-built-in-error-handling-methods) even suggests writing your own Laravel bootstrap application instead of using the default one, breaking Laravel framework semantics, but that's just plain mad.

I have also tried looking at configuration values for Ignition by publishing ignition config file via

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider" --tag="ignition-config"
```

But that file has nothing to configure, the only thing you can do is to hide the "share" message in the error.

I just want a simple classic php error page with file/line/error, no stack traces, or **no html markup**. The error page makes it really difficult to debug output in anything else than a web browser.

Comment: What did you write in the `render()` method of your exception handler that caused an error? You can just remove the Ignition package, although it would then fall back to Whoops.

Comment: And if you're returning HTML pages, yes they're typically difficult to debug outside a web browser. What are you doing that returns HTML outside the context of a web browser?

Comment: it depends; either it's testing something via shell command, or debugging a raw request for Lighthouse via curl (https://lighthouse-php.com/master/digging-deeper/file-uploads.html#client-side-usage), or using a request simulation app like ARC/PostMan, a lot of cases really. actually i'm debugging more often in everything else but the classic web browser mostly, especially if you're writing backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply override the `render()` method in your app's exception handler. Per comments in [the base class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L315), this method must return a response object.

```php
public function render($request, \Throwable $e)
{
    return response()->view("exception", ["exception" => $e]);
}
```

Then make your blade view look however you want.

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>Exception</title>
<body>
<p>
Exception of type <code>{{ get_class($exception) }}</code>
thrown in <code>{{ $exception->getFile() }}</code>
on line <code>{{ $exception->getLine() }}</code>.
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: oh thank you! couldn't find that it needs a `response()`, that's why i kept getting error 500